# Why can't I set header with Android HTTPURLConnection?

Tags: android

So I'm trying to connect to a REST server with HTTPURLConnection. The HTTPGET request needs to be of content-type application/json. When I use `setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");` the value is overriden to "text/html" but when I use `setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");` the Content-Type is set to application/json. Why can't I use Content-Type when specifying? Clarification is greatly appreciated.

My current guess is that `"Accept"` works with HTTPGET and `"Content-Type"` is for HTTPPOST.

More code:

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
//connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-accept-and-content-type-http-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the `Content-Type` header in an HTTP request would be for the type of content being *sent* as the body, and is used on requests like `POST` and `PUT`. `Accept` is the header that indicates what MIME types the requester would like to *receive* in a response.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the HTTP documentation on header and figured the same. Was just confused because it said Content-Type for both.